# hugo blog json Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError:

Tags: json, blogs, hugo

I'm trying to build a blog with hugo, but got error showing below:

Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Expected property name or '}' in JSON at position 1
And I found this happens at index.json: the fuzzy search module.

```json
{{- $.Scratch.Add "index" slice -}}
{{- range .Site.RegularPages -}}
    {{- $.Scratch.Add "index" (dict "title" .Title "description" .Params.description "content" .Content "image" .Params.image "permalink" .Permalink) -}}
{{- end -}}
{{- $.Scratch.Get "index" | jsonify -}}
```

Could anyone help me figure it out❤